# Ionic two side menus pattern no autoscrolling when adding more content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Can someone help me to understand why autoscolling of the content doesnt work?
If you press the button on the header a new message will be added to the main content. As soon as you`ll get more lines than can fin on the screen they will not autoscroll.

`plnkr.co/edit/hRCC6PBVkINJhTj75D0u?p=preview`

Comment: I think that's just default behaviour for any browser. you'll have to use the ionicScrollDelegate to scrolll to the bottom if you want to have that behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's default behaviour for any browser.

If you want to scroll to the bottom of the page after adding an item you will have to do it yourself.

Ionic provides the **$ionicScrollDelegate** for this kind of work.

In the controller:

```
 $scope.addMessage = function() {
   $scope.messages.push({
     content: 'bla-bla-bla ' + $scope.messages.length,
     username: 'John Nash'
   });
   $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom(true);
 };
```

In the view:

```
 <button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-people" ng-click="addMessage()"></button>
```

You can check the working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mLsiGuOvEDT1011SRyfz?p=preview).

Comment: Thx, this helped... I will try to change the sample, because my original app still doesnt work (

Comment: Make surr to change the html template to match. :)